# Permission on OpenLiteSpeed Server localhost with Magento 2

Tags: cache, installation, permissions, file-permissions, litespeed

I'm using CentOS 8 as my OS on my laptop and currently running OpenLiteServer (lsphp73) and have been successfully installed phpmyadmin and magento 2.3.4. Then, it comes with a problem that everytime I want to run something related to cache it always said:

Permission denied / Operation not permitted because /var/cache owned by nobody:nobody always has 775 file permission.

I have to chown first with my username and do some bin/magento command then change it back to nobody:nobody to make it run on localhost subfolder and show in the browser.

It's not a big problem but quite irritated by this. I'm quite new with CentOS 8 anyway and trying to learn a bit deeper in Magento. Has anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: You should always use nobody user to edit or run magento command, never use root or any other user

Comment: that's precisely what I'm going to do and trying to find the command, tried this one  "su - nobody -s /bin/bash" but I always get authentication failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not about operating system, this is only permissions.

if your webserver/php user is nobody, then you better run all commands as nobody.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

```
su -c "Your command right here" -s /bin/bash nobody

sudo su -c "Your command right here" -s /bin/bash nobody

su nobody -s /bin/bash -c "Your command right here" -s /bin/bash

sudo su nobody -s /bin/bash -c "Your command right here"
```

or you go into nobody environment:

```
 su - nobody -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this su - nobody -s /bin/bash as it is more persistent solution in dev time, but it always got authentication failur on my terminal

Comment: Got, it, so i have to login into the root first, then do the command, sudo is not working. Thank you @MagenX